# Can Virtual PC use the Boot Camp Windows Partition?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, virtualization

Both Parallels and VMWare allow you to set up a virtual machine using your existing Boot Camp partition. Does [Virtual PC for mac](http://www.microsoft.com/australia/office/mac/virtualpc7/default.aspx) have a similar feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No as Virtual PC is form PowerPC macs and not Intel ones. 
You will need an intel virtualization product e.g. VirtualBox which is free or Parallels or VMWare